# WCF REST: The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Json'. Expected message format is 'Raw'

Tags: c#, json, rest, wcf, postman

So I've seen many questions reagrding an error *the other way around*, but not this way.

In my WCF Service I've defined the method like:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "v1/posttest")]
void PostTest(Stream incoming);
```

In my request header I've set Content-Type to application/json

So everything should work, right? However, I get a 400 Bad Request error and the notification you see in the question title.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just realized that this isn't the exact phrasing of the output, because I initially translated it from German. So just to be thorough: It's actually "... contains an unrecognized http body format value 'Json'. The expected body format value is 'Raw'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I should've just tried the most obvious thing... Removing the Content-Type header in my client solved the problem.

It still seems unintuitive to me, can anyone explain why WCF does that?

Answer (score 0):

Very nice! Thank you a lot.

This runs perfectly:

```
read: {
        url: "http://localhost:33473/Service2.svc/GetProfile", //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // tells the web service to serialize JSON
        type: "POST", //use HTTP POST request as the default GET is not allowed for svc
      }
```